# Is there a way to match columns in excel? without it having a row name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dataset

So I have this dataset in excel:

```
A       B
11431 11368
11651 11368
11698 11431
13054 11651
13889 11698
15178 13054
15321 13889
15990 15178
16401 15321
16463 15990
...   ...
```

What I want to do is match each pair, and remove those from the dataset. I want to check which values are not included compared to each column.

I tried the MATCH function, but to no success... I tried it like this: MATCH(B1, A1:.. , 0)

Do you know of a better way to do this? Or am I using MATCH wrong? Some help would be much appreciated!

Comment: just do: `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,A:A,0))`  It will return `TRUE` if exists and `FALSE` if not.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you, however this returns "#name?" in the cell, instead of TRUE or FALSE

Comment: @Carnoise what language version of Excel are you using?   Perhaps a non-English one?

Comment: @ScottCraner yes a dutch version, perhaps that is where the issue lies.....

Comment: This might be too late but would a combination of ISNUMBER and SEARCH or possibly just SEARCH work?